# Alternative to multiple try/except statements to check if a field exists

Tags: json, api, python-2.7

I am pulling some information from the Facebook Graph Explorer API. The output of the API is a JSON object.
Sometimes the output contains the fields I'm looking for (i.e. education, school name etc.) and sometimes it doesn't. In order to compensate for this, I've had to write a `try/except/else` block for each json field I'm looking for:

```
 # gender
 try:
     gender=json_dict['gender']

     if gender=='male':
         gender= unicode('M')
     elif gender=='female':
         gender=unicode('F')
 except:
     pass

 #birthday    
 try:
     birthday=json_dict['birthday']

     if len(birthday)==10:
         birthday=int(birthday[6:])
     else:
         birthday=unicode('NULL')
 except:
     pass

 #hometown id
 try:
     hometown_id=int(json_dict['hometown']['id'])
 except:
     pass
```

and on and on. This approach works, but it just seems kind of... unwieldly? It works for my purposes, because I'm only looking for a half dozen fields or so.  Is there better/more clever way to scale this process up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `dict.get(key)` or `dict.get(key, defaultValue)`.

```
try:
    gender=json_dict['gender']

    if gender=='male':
        gender= unicode('M')
    elif gender=='female':
        gender=unicode('F')
except:
    pass
```

Would translate to

```
gender=json_dict.get('gender')
if gender=='male':
        gender= unicode('M')
elif gender=='female':
        gender=unicode('F')
else:
     gender = None # is the default case. no need to write that.
```

or

```
gender={'male':u'M', 'female':u'F'}.get(json_dict.get('gender'))
```

Alternatively you can test with `in`:

```
if 'gender' in json_dict:
    gender=json_dict['gender']

    if gender=='male':
        gender= unicode('M')
    elif gender=='female':
        gender=unicode('F')
else: pass# gender is not defined, NameError possible
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you **shouldn't** use `except` without specifying what you want to catch. It can leads to some debugging problems.

In your case, you can use the [`dict.get()` method](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get):

> Return the value for `key` if `key` is in the dictionary, else `default`. If `default` is not given, it defaults to `None`, so that this method never raises a [`KeyError`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/exceptions.html#exceptions.KeyError).

So we get something like:

```
genders = {'male': unicode('M'), 'female': unicode('F')}
# if gender isn't found or isn't equal to 'male' or 'female', we return 'NULL'
gender = genders.get(json_dict.get('gender'), unicode('NULL'))

birthday = json_dict.get('birthday')
if len(birthday) == 10:
    birthday = int(birthday[6:])
else:
    birthday = unicode('NULL')
```

and so on